Confused with "inline" keyword in C
#include <stdio.h>

inline int b(int x) {
    return x*2;
};

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World %d", b(3));
    return 0;
}

Output:

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccGGQWnl.o: in function 'main':
main.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to 'b'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


This made me:
Dude, ain't all the functions on the same page (i.e. translation unit)? Why doesn't that work?
I  wonder what mechanism prevents the compiler from seeing the definition just above and why it is designed that way.

EDIT:
SO community is strict again. The question is not about fixing the code but about the reason behind.

Use static inline int b

@Barmar Thank you for your reply. I wonder why it is (or it must be) designed that way.

I'll bet the rationale is somewhere in the linked question.

@Barmar You bet, but I couldn't locate.

I added another duplicate that has more details from the standard.

@Xfce4 "This is particularly useful if you want to put a function into a shared library, but also make the function body available for optimization (eg inlining or specialization). Assuming a sufficiently smart compiler, this allows you to recover many of the benefits of C++ templates without having to jump through preprocessor hoops."?

@Barmar Thank you. I have read but did not understand much. Will try again later.

The real point is that there's little reason to use inline on functions that are called from the same compilation unit where they're defined. The compiler can inline the function call itself if it seems beneficial, as part of normal optimization.

@GSerg That didn't sink in... Barmar Is this valid for all compilers?

@Xfce4, it depends on the compiler whether and under what conditions it will inline functions whose definitions are accessible at the point of call.  Being declared with the inline keyword is not necessarily among those conditions.  Modern compilers generally will inline simple enough functions when optimization is enabled, for some definition of "simple enough".  But any compiler can perform such inlining at its own discretion.

Tangential: The semicolon after the close brace for the inline function marks the end of an empty declaration.  You do not need a semicolon there; remove it.

Thank you all. I had already read that inline keyword was an optimization hint to the compiler, not a restriction. But I wonder what the language designers aimed by making inline functions not visible in the same translation unit.
